# Getting error: Route() in Route cannot be applied to String

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

I'm designing a Java based MongoDB app and I've ran into a snag when working with Spark.

```
package com.tengen;

import spark.Request;
import spark.Response;
import spark.Route;
import spark.Spark;

public class HelloWorldSparkStyle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Spark.get(new Route("/") {
            @Override
            public Object handle(Request request, Response response) {
                return "Hello World From Spark";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

On new `Route("/")` I get the error `Route() in route cannot be applied to java.lang.string`.

I'm confused as to why this doesn't work as I've followed their code exactly.
[image]

Comment: The error means that class `Route` does not have a constructor that takes a `String` as an argument. Find the docs for the `Route` class and find out how you have to use it instead. Maybe the tutorial you are looking at is for an older or newer version of Spark than what you are using.

Comment: If you download the homework, the POM file has all the versions the class is using.  I loaded the POM into eclipse and was able to compile their homework using the same style they used in the lecture. The halt() in the exception handler was another issue, but that went away as well.  I assume at some point they are going to have to update the course material.

Comment: Thank you all for the help I've solved the problem! But why so many down votes? I'm confused!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This should probably be posted on the MongoDB class forum, but I ran into a similar issue. Looks like the get method changed from when the course material was produced.  The get now requires a path and a Route

> get(path, Route)

```
import spark.Request;
import spark.Response;
import spark.Route;
import spark.Spark;

public class HelloWorldSparkStyle {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Spark.get("/", new Route() {
                public Object handle(final Request request, final Response response){
                return "Hello World from Spark";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I used spark-core-1.1.1.jar it worked fine for me, may be the newer versions of Spark(version 2.0.0) support some different syntax.So if you are using the latest version then you can follow the example given by Mike or just add spark-core-1.1.1.jar to your classpath your example will work fine

Comment: If you're doing the mongodb university course, its better to change the Spark version to 1.1.1 rather than using the latest version of Spark and facing problems during rest of the course.

Answer (score 0):

That would work in Spark 1. In Spark 2 is recommended by Spark the following (source: http://sparkjava.com/news.html):

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/", (req, res) -> "Hello World From Spark");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Implementation of Spark Java framework needs to use directory out of Route. So you have to correct your code as follow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    spark.Spark.port(PortNumber);
    Spark.get("/", new Route() {
            public Object handle(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
                return "This is a sample page";
            }
        });
}
```

actually, "/" is the resource to your program. And if you want to change the default spark.Spark.port(PortNumber).

Answer (score 0):

Change the version of Spark in the POM file from the exercise files you download from handout. That fixed issue for me.